# Upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and now monitor goes to sleep at boot

Tags: 21.10

After upgrading to the latest version of Ubuntu 21.10 my monitor goes into power savings mode after boot. I am running an old Dell PowerEdge server. I'm not running any third-party drivers, and I'm connected via VGA. The monitor works just fine during post and will show the Ubuntu splash screen, but the monitor goes to sleep when I get to the Ubuntu login screen. I am not able to login through the gui. A fix will need to be applied through the command line. I do have SSH access. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE.  I just did a fresh installation of 21.10 and the problem is exactly the same. For clarification, I have a single Dell monitor attached via VGA to a Dell PowerEdge T620 server. I am going back to Ubuntu 20.04.3.

Comment: how do you know its a sleep issue versus a graphics driver issue ?    anything showing up when issuing  `dmesg` ?

Comment: I said the monitor was going to sleep/power savings mode. I didn't mean the server was going into "sleep mode" I'll try that thanks. This happened immediately after upgrading to 21.10. I was just using the drivers that the previous installation installed by default. Nothing special. No third-party anything.